# Sending Player to another Server through Bungee

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So I've tried to send players to the lobby server when they type "/lobby" by using this code:

```
Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand((Player) player, "server lobby");
```

But in game, it returns "Unknown Command. Type "/help" for help."
I've also read to try this code, but I don't know what to put in place of "a", "b", and "c"

```
ByteArrayDataOutput out = ByteStreams.newDataOutput();
out.writeUTF("a");
out.writeUTF("b");    
//applies to the player you send it to. aka Kick To Server.
Player player = Bukkit.getPlayerExact("c");
player.sendPluginMessage(this, "BungeeCord", out.toByteArray());
```

So my question is why does the first method not work? Also, how do you make the second solution work? Is there code I need to put in the bungee server?

Answer (score 3):

`ByteArrayDataOutput out = ByteStreams.newDataOutput();
out.writeUTF("Connect");
out.writeUTF("ServerName");
player.sendPluginMessage(PluginObject, "BungeeCord", out.toByteArray());`

This is what you are looking for. To answer your question, "a" is always "Connect". "b" is the name of the server that you want to connect to (In your case this is "lobby"), and "c" will the name of the player (This is because in the example that you've supplied your getting the player by their name, however if you've already got the player object, this isn't needed).

And just so that you understand why dispatchCommand doesn't work, it's because when you do /server on your client it sends a packet to the Bungeecord as that's what your client is connected to, and it will intercept that command packet read it and see that it's a server command. It will then proceed to connect you to the right server. If you use dispatchCommand  on the Bukkit server it will execute the command as though it just received an command packet, which means it never sends out any sort of message to the bungeecord or to the client to get it to execute a command. The dispatchCommand method will only be run on the bukkit server.

The reason that the second solution works is because in the Minecraft protocol there's this thing called the plugin messaging channel, for custom messages between the client and the server. And yet again as the Bungeecord sits in the middle of the client and the server, it listens on certain messages, and any of them tagged with Connect will connect a player to the specified server. I hope this makes sense.